# Deploying MVC project to remote iis server with Umbraco

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, umbraco, web-deployment

I'm running into an issue where I'm trying to publish through Visual Studio, but publishing the site doesn't copy out the App_Data folder, which causes the site to crash when it's run, because it's trying to write to a file that doesn't exist. To remedy this, I figured I could just manually copy out the App_Data folder, which did help, however there are still files not present, for example this is my current error:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\App_Data\TEMP\PluginCache\umbraco-plugins.{machine-name}.hash' is denied
```

Which tells me that Umbraco isn't writing out the new files for the remote machine it's now running on. My question then is, how do I get Umbraco to generate all the files it needs to generate to run properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct [file permissions](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/setup/install/permissions) set that are required by Umbraco:

**/Web.config** Modify / Full control
Only needed for setting database and version Information during installation. So can be set to read-only afterwards for enhanced security

**/App_Code**   Modify / Full control
Should always have modify rights as the folder and its files are used for dynamically loading in and generating dlls

**/App_Data**   Modify / Full control
Should always have modify rights as the folder and its files are used for cache and storage

**/Bin**    Modify / Full control
Needed for installing packages, if no packages are installed, this can be set to read accees only

**/Config** Modify / Full control
Only needed for setting database and version Information during installation. So can be set to read-only afterwards for enhanced security

**/Css**    Modify / Full control
Should always have modify rights as the folder and its files are used for css files

**/MacroScripts**   Modify / Full control
Should always have modify rights as the folder and its files are used for Razor files

**/Masterpages**    Modify / Full control
Should always have modify rights as the folder and its files are used for template files

**/Media**  Modify / Full control
Should always have modify rights as the folder and its files are used for media files uploaded via Umbraco cms interface

**/Scripts**    Modify / Full control
Should always have modify rights as the folder and its files are used for script files

**/Umbraco**    Modify / Full control
For upgrades and package installation, it should have modify rights, but can be set to read-only afterwards

**/Umbraco_client** Modify / Full control
For upgrades and package installation, it should have modify rights, but can be set to read-only afterwards

**/UserControls**   Modify / Full control
Modify rights are needed for installing packages

**/Views**  Modify / Full control
Should always have modify rights as the folder and its files are used for template, partial view and macro files

**/Xslt**   Modify / Full control
Should always have modify rights as the folder and its files are used for macro files

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, first off in App_Data, remove everything in there except packages, then go into iis and on your site, right click, edit permissions -> Security tab -> edit -> Add -> Add the name of the site (myapp, myapp.com, etc.), give full control, and your problem should be solved, the site will be able to generate any files it needs to generate.